# Manually do the work of find_package by specifying the paths ons the command line

Tags: cmake

A colleague has a project which uses a hand-written Makefile with hard-coded library paths. So for instance the `CXXFLAGS` and the `LDFLAGS` are set like the following:

```
-I/home/personA/libraries/eigen-3.2.7
-I/home/personA/libraries/boost_1_60_0
-I/home/personB/hdf5-1.8.17/include

-L/home/personA/libraries/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/
-L/home/personB/hdf5-1.8.17/lib
```

Nobody has direct administrative rights on this machine, so just installing the Debian packages with those libraries will involve nagging the administrator to install them. And even if he does, there might be a different dependency that is not in the repositories.

In my CMake file, I have this:

```
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS C CXX)
include_directories(${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system program_options)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_package(OpenMP)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

On my Fedora workstation, this works just fine. On my Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine, it also works, it also builds on Travis CI. However, this project runs on our compute cluster and the dependencies are in really odd places.

So I would like to invoke `cmake` in a way that tells it that I already know that include and library flags it needs and not even bother to look for a `FindEigen3.cmake` file (which is not there).

Is there some way to override the `find_package` and just specify the paths manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let the user set the variables that `find_package` would set manually. Then skip the `find_package` altogether:

```
if(NOT DEFINED EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS)
    find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
endif()
include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

This has the advantage that one does not even need an `FindEigen3.cmake` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) does only look for the libraries/include paths until it has found the requested package and stores a successful finding fact in `_FOUND` variables.

So in your case - taken the `Eigen3` example - you can do:

```sh
> cmake -D Eigen3_FOUND:BOOL=ON -D EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/personA/libraries/eigen-3.2.7 ..
```

Comment: The problem is that on the target system there is not even a `FindEigen3.cmake` file. So I have now chosen a different approach which is similar to yours and does not require that file to be installed.